# Wikipedia Search API

Tags: javascript, html, wikipedia-api

I am trying to code a Wikipedia search and return script. What I am trying to achieve is when a user enters a search query in my text box, it searches Wikipedia for that query and returns the result. *very simple*. I am having problems using Wikipedia API and Don't understand it all. If anyone could help me or knows a tutorial site that would benefit me, I'll be greatfull.

Comment: Did you read everythink here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php ?

Comment: @wallyk 'possible duplicate of Is there a Wikipedia API'. I'm not asking if there is a API - I know there is one. This is a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/using-wikipedia-api-demo-source-code-example/3076/). Might be of help.