# Is it possible to write a search engine algorithm that show's an iframe based off of the searched keywords?

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, iframe

I was wondering if I could and how I would write a search engine algorithm that takes the keyword from the search in a search bar, and finds the best possible solution or solutions(in my case one or more of the Iframes) and only showed the best solution or solutions through one off the following languages:

```
html, css, javascript
```

Here is the code for the iframes and search bar

```
    <!-- CSS -->

<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">        

    <style>
        body {
    color: purple;
    background-color: #663300 }
    </style>

    <script>
function virtualSubmit(form){
    var text = form.searchtext.value;
    var targets = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
        items = targets.length;

    for(var i = 0; i<items; i++){
        var target = targets[i],
            url = target.getAttribute('data-url');
        target.src = url + text;
    }

    return false;
}
    </script>

    <body>

        <!--The Search bar as well-->
<form onsubmit="return virtualSubmit(this)";>
    <input name="searchtext" type="text" />
    <input type="image" src="Searchbutton.png" alt="Search Button" height="20" width="20"/>
</form>

    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/custom"
            data-url="http://www.google.com/custom?q="
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250"></iframe>

    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki"
            data-url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250"></iframe>


    <iframe src="http://m.dictionary.com/definition"
            data-url="http://m.dictionary.com/definition/"
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250"></iframe>
```

at the least I need to know how to hide an Iframe based on a class or function.

Here is what I am asking in more depth:

I believe he/she wants to build some type of UI for search using multiple search / content providers. Additionally, the search providers for a particular query need to be sorted in terms of the 'quality' of results - results will only be displayed for the top search provider for that query.

–  MjrKusanagi

Comment: I don't know if you can, but someone can. How is too general of a question. It will be easier for you to get help if you have a specific question and you show, in code, what you've already tried or read.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I believe he/she wants to build some type of UI for search using multiple search / content providers. Additionally, the search providers for a particular query need to be sorted in terms of the 'quality' of results - results will only be displayed for the top search provider for that query.

Comment: Thats exactly right @MjrKusanagi and I have a team but I just need to know if its possible before I attempt at doing such A thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding possibility: Yes, this is possible. However, you need to make sure that the content providers will allow you to access content inside of their iframe. Certain content providers may have policies and terms of service that forbid this type of use of their content.

Additionally, I believe that most browsers enforce a same-origin policy, meaning the JavaScript loaded from your website at `www.example.com` will not be able to do anything with the data inside of an iframe pointing to `www.google.com`.

Regarding methodology: The proper way to approach this is to look for an API for each search/content provider that meets your needs. For example, there is a [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) (100 search queries per day for free) and a [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) (see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041747/wikipedia-search-api)). After you have an understanding of the APIs you want to employ, it should also be clearer how to proceed with implementation.

Comment: Just the info I was looking for, I shall share this with the rest of my team. Thanks so much!